# Debounce ignoring timeout in unit tests

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, rx-java2

I have this method to fetch search result from api

```
public void fetchSearchResults(Observable<String> searchObservable) {
    searchObservable
        .filter(search -> !TextUtils.isEmpty(search))
        .debounce(700, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnNext(search -> getView().showLoader)
        .switchMap(search -> apiService.fetchSearchResults(search)) //Api call is executed on an io scheduler
        .subscribe(consumer, errorConsumer);
}
```

and I wrote this JUnit test for this method:

```
@Test
public void fetchSearchResultsTest() {
    TestScheduler testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
    Observable<String> nameObservable = Observable.just("","FA")
            .concatMap(search -> Observable.just(search).delay(100,
                           TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, testScheduler));
    testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    verify(view, never()).showLoader();
    
    testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    verify(view, never()).showLoader();
}
```

But the test fails on the last `verify` statement with message

> org.mockito.exceptions.verification.NeverWantedButInvoked
>
> view.showLoader();

I have tried passing a `TestScheduler` to the `debounce` operator and setting the default computation scheduler as a `TestScheduler` through `RxJavaPlugins` but the result does not change, the test still fails.

If the test is failing then that would mean that the `debounce` operator is sending the event right through it ignoring timeout passed in it's arguments. I don't know if this correct but this is as far I understand. So, my question is how can I fix this test and control the events from the `debounce` operator like I'm doing with the source observable with `TestSchedulers`?

Comment: Where/what is the TestScheduler class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is failing because of the `onCompleted()` that occurs when the second item is emitted. The documentation says that `debounce()` will issue the final item immediately that it receives `onCompleted()`.

To make your test work, either concatenate an `Observable.never()`, or add more items into the pipeline.

Here is an article on [using debounce](http://www.jayrambhia.com/notes/rxjava-debounce) for doing auto-completion.

Comment: You were right, adding 3rd element to the source observable resolved the issue